# "Send" popout showing, "Like" isn't

Tags: css, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've installed a Like button on my blog, as well as the Facebook send button.

When I click "Send", the popout comes out and appears nicely with a prompt on who to send the post to.

But, when you click "Like", no popout comes. It's not the "overflow:visible" problem, because the Send popout works. Very confusing and odd, I think...

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div style="overflow:visible;" class="fb-like" data-href="http://liamgetreu.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="lucida grande"></div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your blog and it looks like there is an iframe being generated for the pop-out, but that pop-out is not being filled in by Facebook.  There is a javascript error that is the probably cause of the issue.

```
uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <http://www.facebook.com> 
to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger
https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/widget/gcm_ppb,
googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/ver=VRKLmt4S1dg.en_US./sv=1
/am=!itqi7GDL5S6I4GqN1g/d=1/  Line 116
```

To find out what javascript is colliding with that Facebook one to cause the error.  I would suggest striping everything off that page one thing at a time until the Facebook script can run without error.  This will tell you what item (or combination of items) was interfering.

Happy troubleshooting!  Let us know what you find.

Comment: I tried to strip it all back, but couldn't find anything. I just find it bizarre that the Send button works but the Like button doesn't. Any other ideas, by any chance?

Comment: You mean you had an empty page with just the code to run the like plugin, and it still failed?  Something is wrong with your server or your host if that is the case.

Comment: Yep -- Are you able to see http://liamgetreu.com/fbtest.htm? I tried it on a couple of different machines and browsers, and still only the Send button works. 

Any idea on what it could be server-side?

Comment: Thank you for the sample.  That is truly bare bones :)  I went back to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and now am seeing strange behaviour in FF 8 from Facebook's own code.  It appears to be broken there too (in a different way).  Let's hope this is a transient bug.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ isbroken in IE9 as well.

Comment: This appears to be a bug with facebook. I just hit up stackoverflow because I am encountering the same symptoms today. The <head> element on the https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_widget_shell.php? iframe is missing any stylesheet references so nothing is being styled.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/227982910612589?browse=search_4f05fd69559c12619973899

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't see there was a "Bugs" section on the Facebook dev website. Thanks Matthew. Hopefully Facebook can fix it soon.

Comment: I found this bug, which seemed to best accurately diagnose the problem I was having. The workaround suggested is sufficient, as you can see at (http://liamgetreu.com/fbtest.htm). Thanks for your help everyone.